# Integration from CRM to Team Foundation Server 2018

Tags: json, tfs, integration, crm

We have CRM where customers create tickets (change requests, incidents...). 
From developer team side we have Team Foundation Server 2018.

To speed up process we would like to automatize entire thing. So, when customer create ticket, to automatic create TFS User Story.

We developed code to take, every time when ticket is created, data and put into JSON file. (will attach code in Github and share a link) 
But now, I just need info, is someone have an idea, how JSON file should looks like which need to post to TFS in order to create new user story.

```
{
    "fields": {
        "System.WorkItemType": "User Story",
        "System.AreaPath": "EJ2TFS",
        "System.TeamProject": "EJ2TFS",
        "System.IterationPath": "EJ2TFS",
        "System.State": "New",
        "System.Reason": "New",
        "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate": "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "System.ChangedBy": "Doe, John <firm\\doej>",
        "System.CreatedBy": "Doe, John <firm\\doej>",
        "System.Title": "Sample task created by POST API",
        "System.Discussion":"test1",
        "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate": "2019-01-31T14:00:00",
        "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority": 2,
        "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea": "Business"
    }
}
```

And error is:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "The request indicated a Content-Type of \"text/plain\" for method type \"POST\" which is not supported. Valid content types for this method are: application/json-patch+json.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssRequestContentTypeNotSupportedException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi",
    "typeKey": "VssRequestContentTypeNotSupportedException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3000
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Comment: Show us the JSON you tried & error you faced.

Comment: JSON file added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your payload need a makeover. I referred couple of code samples & sharing this snippet. (Pls test this, I didn’t get a chance to test it)

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$User Story?api-version=5.0

[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "My first user story"
  }
]
```

[MS documentation example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#examples)

[GitHub sample](https://github.com/redarrowlabs/vsts-restapi-samplecode/blob/master/VSTSRestApiSamples/WorkItemTracking/WorkItems.cs)