# Is there an API to link CRM to Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, dynamics-crm, crm

We are in the process of implementing Microsoft CRM and already use Azure DevOps. Is there an API that links CRM to DevOps?

Comment: It’s unclear. You want to do what? Deployments?

Comment: We want to know if we have the ability to create a bug in devops from a support ticket in CRM at the click of a button?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely you can create a bug in Azure DevOps (TFS) using REST API from Dynamics CRM ribbon button click.

1. Add a button in CRM ribbon using Ribbon workbench
2. Use a custom JavaScript action using web resource for that button command
3. From that JS webresource, using `XMLHttpRequest` hit the [Azure DevOps REST API with a proper payload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54585737/7920473)

**No code solution**: You can use MS Flow to create a bug using connectors & invoke the Flow within Dynamics using OOB Flow button.